# How to restart and update a widget from a system reboot android

Tags: android, android-widget

i have an appwidget that runs successfully. now when the phone is being rebooted,
the widget loses all its data and just sits on the home screen. since i can't update the widget from a broadcast receiver when the phone reboots, i created a notification
that leads to the configuration activity of the widget. Nothing works after the user sets the configuration again and leaves the configuration activity; the idle widget just remains there?(the user has to delete the widget and create a widget again).. Am assuming i am not receiving the widget id correctly or am i doing it wrongly in broadcast receiver and suppose to move all the code to onEnable in the widget method?.. How do i refresh the widget correctly. Please bear in mind that all widget updates are done from a service.

by the way i have this code in broadcast receiver for boot_completed action:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String  info = context.getResources().getString(R.string.restart_setting);

     int[] allids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class));
        for(int appWidgetId:allids){

        NotificationManager mnotifyManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Weather Update", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notify.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notify.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    Intent Settings = new Intent(context, WidgetConfigure.class);
    Settings.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, weatherSettings, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Weather Update", info, pending);
        notify.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notify.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        mnotifyManager.notify(WEATHER_NOTIFICATION_ID , notify);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have recently tried to move this code to onEnabled() in the widget cycle, but it still doesn't refresh the widget. is it possible at all?..

Comment: y r using seperate broadcast if appwidgetprovider itself contains onReceive method

Comment: better u use the onReceive of appwidgetprovider to handle the id and other component of widget in easy way

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem this morning and tried to solve it with listening to the  boot_completion intent. It doesn't work this way with widgets. Here's what I found.

- To get notified about a reboot, you need to receive `android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATION_AVAILABLE` in addition to boot_completed and the permission of `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.
- But the whole truth is that an additional intent is not necessary. After reboot the `onEnable` and `onUpadate` of the BroadcastReceiver get called anyway.

So, the solution I've implemented, stores the config of each widget in a file, with the widget Id as part of the filename. And in `onUpdate` of the receiver I initialize the widget again (with click listener and all that)

Outcome is, that after reboot it takes a moment but then the widgets (all) look good and work like expected.

Comment: exactly how I do it too.

Comment: Good things need time :-)

Comment: is this solution to that or need to do anything else?

Comment: The actual solution is implemented beginning with the sentence 'So, the solution I've implemented...'. Sorry, that I described what's not working first.